# ¿Cómo probar mi pagina web en un celular Android localmente?

Tags: html, android, css, test

estoy haciendo una web responsive, y me gustaría poder probarla en mi celular.
Lo he intentado pasando los archivos de la web y abriendo con el Chrome, pero solo me muestra el html, y no lee el css.
Estuve buscando por internet, y no he encontrado nada que solucione mi problema.
Mi pagina no la he subido a ningun hosting por que es mas simplemente para pruebas y me gustaria poder probarla localmente sin tener que subirla a la nube.
Conocen alguna app(Android) que permita hacer esto?

Comment: Siempre puedes probar con las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador. No va a ser 100% exacto, pero en general se acerca bastante (especialmente cuando es Chrome y Android).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, tu pc y tu celular deben estar en la misma red, segundo, debes utilizar un servidor local para tu sitio (Node,apache, tomcat, etc), tercero, desde el navegador del celular accede a la ip de tu pc y el puerto donde se esta ejecutando el servidor con tu sitio, eso debería funcional.
Por otra parte, para facilitarte las cosas la consola del navegador chrome trae una función llamada "Toogle device toolbar" en la parte superior izquierda, eso debe funcionar mejor para hacer pruebas.
Suerte

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta David, te hago una consulta, entiendo la primera forma yo uso el XAMP para probar todo localmente, pero no me queda claro, como tendría que poner en el navegador del celular para que se visualice la pagina, ¿Cómo seria la estructura del enlace?, por tirar un ejemplo se me ocurre:
192.168.0.1::80

Comment: Suponiendo que la ip de tu pc es 192.168.1.15 y el puerto con el que actualmente tienes montado XAMP es el puerto 80, lo que en tu pc daría lugar a '192.168.1.15:80' o bien 'localhost:80', lo que tienes que hacer es desde tu celular en el navegador acceder a la ip de tu pc (Nota: La ip tal cual, no un 'localhost') y utilizar el puerto correspondiente. "192.168.1.15:80" desde el navegador del celular.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas XAMP la cosa es facil lo unico que tienes que hacer es poner a tu celular en la misma red y al abrir chrome en tu celular donde pones la url escribes la ip de tu maquina/el nombre de tu proyecto

Comment: Hola, te sugiero leer [answer]. Cuándo una pregunta está incompleta, es mejor solicitar aclaraciones del AP antes de responder y responder hasta que la pregunta es clara, pues de otra forma te arriesgas a dar una respuesta para un problema distinto del del AP, y en StackOverflow, se persigue tener preguntas y respuestas de calidad que luego ayuden a otras personas. Un saludo.